# How to trigger an event from the keyboard on keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how e.g. this website did the following 'easter egg':

When you type 'dance' on your keyboard on this page: http://wistia.com/about/yearbook the images change to people dancing.

How could I implement something similar? E.g.

```
$('#image').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==70){
        // pressed 'f', do something...
    }
});
```

Comment: You could create a hidden text field and continuosly add focus to it. Then read the value on the keyup event and look for `dance`

Comment: I'd take a look at [this](http://viget.com/inspire/breaking-the-konami-code-adding-an-easter-egg-to-your-site). They use the konami code, but the code gives you a kick in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append the input to a string, and check to verify that the last bit of the input = the characters you are looking for.

```
var secret = "6865786769"; //dance
var input = "";

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    input += e.which;

    check_input();
});

function check_input() {
    if(input.substr(input.length-secret.length) == secret) {
        //the secret code
        alert('Dance');
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v7ate4kz/2/) is a working jsfiddle.